# Can I generate tailwind css in another way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, tailwind-css

I would like to generate all the grid related css to a file with a few modifications like prefix and media queries using the tailwind.config.js file, **without** having to have them specified in a html,js,framework file?

Is that possible?

As I can see it now purge/safelist with a regex is the option?

like

```
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    enabled: true,
    options: {
      safelist: ['/place-/g', '/justify-/g']
    }
  }
}
```

Thankful for any help on this.

**Please note**, I'm not into in setting up a "fake html page" with classes, as my use case might grow overtime.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, think you're just missing the `content` criteria & the `standard` key for the safelist object?

```js
  purge: {
        content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}",],
        enabled: true,
        options: {
            safelist: {
                standard: [/^grid-col/, /^grid-row/]
            }
        }
    },
```

This may be useful to you:
https://purgecss.com/safelisting.html#in-the-css-directly

--

If you just need tailwind grids, perhaps an alternative like this may help:
https://github.com/VeronQ/tailwind-grid

Comment: That's a good catch and I just wrote my regex for this example code. My question boils down to, is purge and safelist the only way to include a specific "field/area/component" css without actually using tailwind in the project? Like the content part is never gone be relevant for me, I'm just looking for a way to generate a css file based with just the grid properties.

Comment: I think the short answer to your question appears to be no, unfortunately. Tailwind doesn't have that same simple way of generating a specific subset, like Bootstrap's "customise & download" option.

Comment: (added tailwind-grid alternative via edit)